# Is it possible query all elements including shadow dom with Polymer?

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

For example, lets say we want to do querySelectorAll('canvas') to get all canvases in the document, including the ones in the shadow dom. Is that possible with polymer?

Answer (score 16):

No. For a period of time there was a proposal whereby you could use the `/deep/` combinator, but it was found to be bad for encapsulation and has been deprecated. Code that relies upon it will break.

Instead, if you need to, you can take an element and look into its shadow root specifically and query within it.

Comment: What about calling querySelectorAll on an html element?

Comment: @positlabs that should work as well with the /deep/ combinator.

Comment: How would you use querySelector within a component? For example, `myComponent.querySelector('/deep/ canvas')` (this doesn't work).

Comment: Figured it out: `myComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('canvas')`